# History of files sent over Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, logging

Does Android keep a history of the files sent via Bluetooth? I didn't see anything like that in the user interface (there's a log of received files, but not sent ones), but maybe there's a hidden log file  somewhere?
I need to check past activity. Installing an app to start logging this now won't help me.

Answer (score 6):

Go to settings and turn on bluetooth. Click menu button and you will see the option `Show received files`. Alternatively every files sent via bluetooth will be stored in a folder named `bluetooth` in storage (if the files are not moved).

Comment: Thanks, though I'm looking for the log of sent files, not received ones. I've updated my post to make it unambiguous.

Comment: Show received files will show both uploaded and downloaded Bluetooth file logs under two tabs. You can view it there.

Comment: What version of Android are you using? I'm using 4.2.2 and I don't see any tab.

Comment: Me neither on 4.3 and 4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

There's a user interface that's providing the log/history of Bluetooth sharing.

To view the log you need to activate Bluetooth and send any file. After sending a notification appears and by clicking it you can view the logs.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I've dismissed the notification at the time, and new notifications of this kind don't show previously sent files.